# ffmpeg conversion stops suddenly

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, rtmp, wowza, ip-camera

I am using FFmpeg converter to push the RTSP stream to RTMP endpoint (Wowza).

ffmpeg -i rtsp://127.0.0.1:554/live0 -c copy -f flv  rtmp://88.888.888.888:1935/live/test

The command first throws below error and proceeds with the conversion.
[image]

I can play the stream from RTMP endpoint, but after a few seconds, FFmpeg stucks and RTMP endpoint stops to stream.

Please Let me know if I am missing anything here.

I am open to use other libraries for pushing RTSP to RTMP endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You can add analyzeduration and probesize options.

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 10M -probesize 10M -i rtsp://127.0.0.1:554/live0 -c copy -f flv rtmp://88.888.888.888:1935/live/test
```

If it failed again, you can try increasing the analyzeduration and probesize options to 20M and 40M.

If still failed, please post the total console log output.